# Should we have a library tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was looking at [Library of Congress filing: "intended for children or young adults"](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/40934/library-of-congress-filing-intended-for-children-or-young-adults/40938#40938) and seeing if the tags were appropriate.  Turns out we have no [library](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/library) tag.

Doing a search, there are [371 posts mentioning the word library](https://writing.stackexchange.com/search?q=library).  Many are answers, not questions, and of course most questions using the word wouldn't benefit from it as a tag.

A few additional questions that would benefit from a [library](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/library) tag include:

- [How to enter a self published book into Russian library](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/38201/how-to-enter-a-self-published-book-into-russian-library?r=SearchResults&s=2|35.9424)
- [book placement in libraries](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/28377/book-placement-in-libraries)
- [How important is an LCCN ? (self publishing)](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/30659/how-important-is-an-lccn-self-publishing)
- [Ownership on slide presentation](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/38887/ownership-on-slide-presentation/38888)

**May I add a [library](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/library) tag?**

Answer (score 1):

Filing a book in a national library such as the Library of Congress for the US is part of the publishing process and should be labelled with the [publishing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publishing) tag.

Getting your book placed in other libraries is part of [marketing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing). It doesn't need a specific library tag either.